# Dynamically maven patching of Java7 libraries

Tags: maven, java-7, java-8, patch

I'd like to have code which by default uses the Java 8, but patch it and generate a java7-compatible jar. In this case is just because the `Optional` usage. Is there any way to include such workflows in the build lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I reply myself how to do it using the [patch plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-patch-plugin) and profiles:

```
<properties>
    <java.classifier>java8</java.classifier>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>${java.classifier}</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>java7</id>
        <properties>
            <java.classifier>java7</java.classifier>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-patch-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <strip>1</strip>
                        <patches>
                            <patch>java7.patch</patch>
                        </patches>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>patch</id>
                            <phase>process-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>apply</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>...</groupId>
                <artifactId>...</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

Not so complex... but there may be better solutions.